# Angular sorting and grouping items in template

Tags: angular, sorting, grouping

I'm using Angular (v4) to display a list of, say, used cars. They can be sorted by make, year, and mileage. What I'd like to do is take this data object and group every object of a certain type into an element depending on what I'm sorting them by.

So imagine a `<ul>` for each **car manufacturer** with an `<li>` containing information on each car in my data object. Thus it will spit something out like this:

```
<ul>
<li>2016 Ford Ranger: 20,000 mi</li>
<li>2015 Ford F150: 48,000 mi</li>
<li>2012 Ford F150: 122,000 mi</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>2015 Fiat 500: 34,000 mi</li>
<li>2017 Fiat Spider: 48,000 mi</li>
<li>2014 Fiat 500: 82,000 mi</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>2013 Jeep Ranger: 64,000 mi</li>
</ul>
```

What is the **best practice** in this occasion? Do I split and sort the array of objects using a function in the .ts file? Do I use a series of *ngIf and *ngFor statements in the template? What would render the page in the most flexible and efficient manner?

**The property by which the objects are sorted is a variable, and every property has a matching numeric ID.**

---

**Edit:** I was reluctant to share my solution, but here it is:

```
  <ul class="cargroup" *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index;">
  // group being the make of car in this instance

    <li *ngFor="let car of this.carList">

      <app-car-info [car]="car" *ngIf="car?.makeId == group.id"></app-task>
     // component that shows all the info about the car

    </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: post your typescript code.

Comment: I'm asking what the best practice is, so that would include how to go about writing anything in typescript. I could imagine in the class I'd have something like `@Input() cars: carList`

Comment: What I would do, is to handle everything in the component. My motto is to try and keep template as clean and tidy as possible and handle all "work" in components. But these are opinion based I would say.

Comment: I would do it in the .ts file. That way your application can be dynamic and you can have your business logic in the .ts file too.